# From the django shell how do you list staff users

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a field to the user profile and need to confirm that the user is staff and active but i cannot figure out a command that will display this.

thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can adapt:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
active_staff = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_staff=True)
```

You could add in a `username=` or similar and if you get an empty result, then you know they don't match the criteria. For info on what's in the default model, see [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/).

Comment: It is probably better to use `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and then `User = get_user_model()` to always get the correct User model.